# How to convert a list(Of string) to an XML file (Visual Basic)

Tags: xml, vb.net, list

I'm trying to make a "to do list" application using a `checkedListBox` to be able to check off the completed tasks. I'm trying to put the items from checkedListBox in a `List(Of String)`, and then put those items on an XML document to be able to load the list on another machine by only transporting the file.

I think I've got the converting the list items into a `List(Of String)`, but I can't find anything on putting that in an XML file. How can I do this?

Here's the code to create the list:

```html
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim itens As List(Of String) = list.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim x = New XElement("ToDos", itens.[Select](Function(i) New XElement("ToDo", i)))`

Comment: You have to `Import System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: I'd recommend looking up XML serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim items As List(Of String) = list.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList()

        Dim xml As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><root></root>"
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)

        Dim root As XElement = doc.Root

        For Each item As String In items
            root.Add(New XElement("Item", item))
        Next

        doc.Save("c:\temp\test.xml")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XElement and Linq with XML literals you can do something like this,

```
    'for testing
    Dim items As New List(Of String) From {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"}

    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <items>
             <%= From i In items
                 Select <item><%= i %></item>
             %>
         </items>

    xe.Save("path here")
```